# Change the file content with bash

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sed

I have a question regarding manipulating a file content using bash. So I have a conf file has the content as below:

```
#set_var EASYRSA_REQ_COUNTRY    "US"                                                                        
#set_var EASYRSA_REQ_PROVINCE   "California"                                                                
#set_var EASYRSA_REQ_CITY       "San Francisco"                                                             
#set_var EASYRSA_REQ_ORG        "Copyleft Certificate Co"                      
#set_var EASYRSA_REQ_EMAIL      "me@example.net"                                                            
#set_var EASYRSA_REQ_OU         "My Organizational Unit"
```

I want to put a line of command in a bash file to automate the process to change from above to uncomment lines:

```
set_var EASYRSA_REQ_COUNTRY    "US"                                                                        
set_var EASYRSA_REQ_PROVINCE   "Texas"                                                                
set_var EASYRSA_REQ_CITY       "Austin"                                                             
set_var EASYRSA_REQ_ORG        "Copyleft Certificate Co"                      
set_var EASYRSA_REQ_EMAIL      "me@google.com"                                                            
set_var EASYRSA_REQ_OU         "My CompanyName"
```

The problem I have is the whitespace and end of line when I try to combine the content to and sed command:

```
sed -e 's/#set_var EASYRSA_REQ_COUNTRY[ \t]*"US"\n#set_var EASYRSA_REQ_PROVINCE[ \t]*"California"\n#set_var EASYRSA_REQ_CITY[ \t]*"San Francisco"\#set_var EASYRSA_REQ_ORG[ \t]*"Copyleft Certificate Co"\n#set_var EASYRSA_REQ_EMAIL[ \t]*"me@example.net"\n#set_var EASYRSA_REQ_OU[ \t]*"My Organizational Unit"\n/set_var EASYRSA_REQ_COUNTRY[ \t]*"US"\nset_var EASYRSA_REQ_PROVINCE[ \t]*"Texas"\nset_var EASYRSA_REQ_CITY[ \t]*"Austin"\set_var EASYRSA_REQ_ORG[ \t]*"Copyleft Certificate Co"\nset_var EASYRSA_REQ_EMAIL[ \t]*"me@google.com"\nset_var EASYRSA_REQ_OU[ \t]*"My CompanyName"\n/g' file.conf
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ `wc -l file.conf`

6 file.conf

$ `cat file.conf`

```
#set_var EASYRSA_REQ_COUNTRY    "US"                                                                        
#set_var EASYRSA_REQ_PROVINCE   "California"                                                                
#set_var EASYRSA_REQ_CITY       "San Francisco"                                                             
#set_var EASYRSA_REQ_ORG        "Copyleft Certificate Co"                      
#set_var EASYRSA_REQ_EMAIL      "me@example.net"                                                            
#set_var EASYRSA_REQ_OU         "My Organizational Unit"
```

---

```
sed -i 's/^#set_var/set_var/; s/California/Texas/; s/San Francisco/Austin/; s/me@example.net/me@google.com/; s/My Organizational Unit/My CompanyName/; 7,$d' file.conf
```

---

$ `wc -l file.conf`

6 file.conf

$ `cat file.conf`

```
set_var EASYRSA_REQ_COUNTRY    "US"                                                                        
set_var EASYRSA_REQ_PROVINCE   "Texas"                                                                
set_var EASYRSA_REQ_CITY       "Austin"                                                             
set_var EASYRSA_REQ_ORG        "Copyleft Certificate Co"                      
set_var EASYRSA_REQ_EMAIL      "me@google.com"                                                            
set_var EASYRSA_REQ_OU         "My CompanyName"
```

Comment: oh nice, that's smart, can you explain why do you have 7,$d in the end? Thank you.

Comment: @kluo To remove anything in or after 7 th line

Comment: @kluo feel free to mark answer as accepted if it helped